# JPA - Sql Server error: Cannot open database "Taijitan" requested by the login

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink

I'm making a Java program that connects to an SQL Server database together with a small team. Their code runs succesfully, but whenever I try to launch the Java application, I get the error: Cannot open database "Taijitan" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:f96fe50c-768a-4e85-8673-3e39a8feb1e4

I already checked my TCP/IP in SQL Server Management / Configuration.
In the netbeans.conf file I changed the JDKhome to jdk10.0.2.
In the env var I added the path to jdk10.0.2. 
I also added the sqljdbc_auth.dll file to programfiles/java/jdk10.0.2/lib and also to bin. In SQL Server Manager I also checked if my Windows account has all the required permissions.

**Persistence unit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="TaijitanPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>domein.Persoon</class>
    <class>domein.Graad</class>
    <class>domein.Locatie</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\sqlexpress:1433;databaseName=Taijitan;integratedSecurity=true;"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Error message**

```
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "Taijitan" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:f96fe50c-768a-4e85-8673-3e39a8feb1e4
Error Code: 4060
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:941)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at persistentie.PersistentieController.<init>(PersistentieController.java:18)
    at domein.Club.<init>(Club.java:16)
    at domein.DomeinController.<init>(DomeinController.java:14)
    at startup.Main.start(Main.java:29)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "Taijitan" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:f96fe50c-768a-4e85-8673-3e39a8feb1e4
Error Code: 4060
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:191)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:78)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at persistentie.GenericDaoJpa.<clinit>(GenericDaoJpa.java:10)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "Taijitan" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:f96fe50c-768a-4e85-8673-3e39a8feb1e4
Error Code: 4060
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:767)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "Taijitan" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:f96fe50c-768a-4e85-8673-3e39a8feb1e4
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:104)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1LogonProcessor.complete(SQLServerConnection.java:4488)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4773)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3581)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:81)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3541)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2395)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2042)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1889)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1120)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:700)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:100)
    ... 26 more
Exception running application startup.Main
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: The error suggests the SQL connection was successful but failed accessing the Taijitan database database. Make sure the Windows account has permissions to access the database.

Comment: @DanGuzman I checked this and it seems my Windows account has all the permissions to acces the database.

Comment: Also check the SQL Server error log to see if there are any additional related messages.

Comment: @DanGuzman I'm working in NetBeans, so I'm not sure where to check this. In SQL Server Manager i'm able to connect with the database.

Comment: In he SSMS Object Explorer tree, you can view the SQL Server error log under Management-->SQL Server Logs-->Current

Comment: @DanGuzman The 'cuurent' log is from last week, so I can't see any information about this problem. 
Currently I am trying to recreate the persistence.xml in Netbeans with the connection string: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\sqlexpress:1433;databaseName=Taijitan;integratedSecurity=true .
When I test this it tells me it can't establish a connection.

Comment: The date of the current log reflects the date it was created and will contain recent messages. Double-click to review the contents.

Comment: @DanGuzman The contect of the log stays empty, as if NetBeans didn't even try to connect.

Comment: The error message is returned by SQL Server as a result of the failed connection so it should be logged. If you don't see it in the error log, the app is trying to connect to a different SQL Server instance. Try running this from SSMS `EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Login failed';`

Comment: @DanGuzman when running this I get a list with the same elements:
A log date, ProcessInfo: Logon, Text: Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]